# How to change background image of label and button randomly on kivy

Tags: python, kivy

i think i found none about changing a background image of label and button randomly, so here is the problem.
Say i have these codes
Py file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import random


class Screen(Screen):
    bg = random.randint(1,5)


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("testing.kv")

class Start(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Start().run()
```

kv file

```
WindowManager:
    Screen:

<Screen>:
    GridLayout:
        size: root.height,root.width
        cols:2
        Label:
            id: label
            canvas:
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
                    source: 'bg_label_1.png'

        Button:
            id: button
            background_normal: 'bg_button_1.png'
```

say i have 5 backgrounds each for the button and label, named bg_label_(1 to 5) abd bg_button_(1 to 5). i want to create a code where if the button is clicked, the code will randomly pick a number from 1 to 5, then change both the background of the label and button according to the rolled number. is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use `Properties`.

But first, don't create a custom class with the same name as its base class. I suggest changing:

```
class Screen(Screen):
```

to something like:

```
class MyScreen(Screen):
```

Reusing common class names can only lead to confusion.

Next, add `Properties` to your new class:

```
class MyScreen(Screen):
    label_bg = StringProperty('bg_label_1.png')
    button_bg = StringProperty('bg_button_1.png')
```

and reference those `Properties` in the `kv`:

```
    Label:
        id: label
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
                source: root.label_bg

    Button:
        id: button
        background_normal: root.button_bg
        on_release: root.change_images()
```

The above `kv` sets the initial images to the same ones that you use in your post, and also sets up a call to a `change_images()` method in the `MyScreen` class.

Add that method to the `MyScreen` class:

```
def change_images(self):
    bg = str(random.randint(1,5))
    self.button_bg = 'bg_button_' + bg + '.png'
    self.label_bg = 'bg_label_' + bg + '.png'
```

This methods sets new values for the `Properties`, and their references in the `kv` insures that the widgets will get updated.